# Como pegar dados de uma array e usar rand sem repetir?

Tags: php, array

Estou fazendo um quiz, e guardei as respostas em uma array, quero que essas respostas apareça de forma aleatório que não repita no quiz.

Usei o seguinte código.

```
<?php
$times = array('', 'Corinthians', 'Santos', 'Flamengo');
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
$rand = array_rand($times, 2);
?>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="quiz1" value="A">
<label for="questao1-A"><?php echo $times[$rand[1]]; ?></label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando o recurso errado.

Existe o `shuffle` para isso, veja no manual em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php.

O `shuffle` faz justamente tornar a array em ordem aleatória, sendo assim a ordem definida é ignorada, inclusive os indices!

A forma mais simples para resolver o que quer é, exatamente:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$times = array('', 'Corinthians', 'Santos', 'Flamengo');
shuffle($times);

foreach($times as $time){
?>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="quiz1" value="A">
<label for="questao1-A"><?= $time ?></label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

[Me teste aqui!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/efa483e9bdc011a0f772cdc5306b3f7e72b28a7c)

**Resultado:**

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="quiz1" value="A">
<label for="questao1-A"></label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="quiz1" value="A">
<label for="questao1-A">Flamengo</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="quiz1" value="A">
<label for="questao1-A">Corinthians</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="quiz1" value="A">
<label for="questao1-A">Santos</label>
</div>
```

> **Nota:**
>   Mudança para o `foreach` é opcional, mas para mim melhora a leitura do
>   código e reduz os inúmeros usos de `[]` junto ao parâmetro, o que pode
>   confundir.

Comment: poh cara, vlwzão, eu tinha achado um tutorial na net, que tinha q fazer função e tals, um codigo de mais ou menos 15 linhas, esse ai salvou brigadão