# É possível randomizar dados de um JSON?

Tags: php, json

Estou fazendo um sistema de Quiz, onde a resposta correta sempre será a primeira alternativa no banco de dados, porém é necessário que ela seja randômica na hora de responder. (PHP)

É possível randomizar os dados dentro de `alternatives`?

```
"questions": [{
    "title": "Qual é a raça de Goku?",
    "image": {
        "path": ""
    },
    "alternatives": [{
        "title": "Sayajins",
        "image": {
            "path": ""
        },
        "correct": true
    }, {
        "title": "Anjo",
        "image": {
            "path": ""
        }
    }, {
        "title": "Android",
        "image": {
            "path": ""
        }
    }],
    "alternativeType": 1
}
```

Comment: Esse código que enviou, está em Javascript! Não ?

Comment: @RafaelLaurindo não, ele está  sendo encodado como json

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar dados de uma array e usar rand sem repetir?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121276/como-pegar-dados-de-uma-array-e-usar-rand-sem-repetir)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer utilizar uma função do PHP chamada shufle(https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php).

Com a função shuffle você pode embaralhar os elementos de um array, no caso, embaralhando as alternativas das questões.

Você pode fazer da seguinte da forma:

```
<?php

$questions = [
    [
        "title" => "Qual é a raça de Goku?",
        "image" => [
            "path" => "",
        ],
        "alternatives" => [
            [
                "title" => "Sayajins",
                "image" => [
                    "path" => "",
                ],
                "correct" => true,
            ], [
                "title" => "Anjo",
                "image" => [
                    "path" => "",
                ],
            ], [
                "title" => "Android",
                "image" => [
                    "path" => "",
                ],
            ],
        ],
        "alternativeType" => 1,
    ],
];

array_map(function ($question) {
    shuffle($question['alternatives']);
}, $questions);
```

Assim, você percorre todas questões e embaralha(suffle), as alternativas, deixando items ordenados de forma randômica.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Por mais que gere o resultado esperado, está utilizando equivocadamente a função `array_map`. Tal função, como o nome diz, foi definida para se definir uma relação entre o valor de entrada e valores de saída, também conhecido por mapa; o que você quer fazer é percorrer o *array* e chamar a função `shuffle`. A função `array_map` não serve para percorrer *array*, para tal você usa `array_walk` ou algum laço de repetição.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e pra verificar se correct existe é e igual a true?